# Get Content of agit respository

Tags: java, rest, http, github

I need a way of getting the content of the GitHub repository in java.
For example I wanna download this file: [Example Repository](https://github.com/Call-for-Code/Project-Sample/blob/main/sample-static-web/css/styles.css)

With a method like this:

```
public String getRepository(String url) {
    String result = // do somthing;
    return result;
}
```

When We call it with

```
  getRepository("github.com/Call-for-Code/Project-Sample/blob/main/sample-static-web/css/styles.css");
```

It shoukd return

```
"/*\n* Copyright 2020-2021 Daniel Krook\n* \n* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); \n* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. \n* You may obtain a copy of the License at\n* \n* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\n* \n* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software\n* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,\n* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.\n* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and\n* limitations under the License.\n*/"
```

Comment: you could clone the repo and then search inside it locally

Comment: Yeah. That's not the problem. I'm working anyway on a private repo. I'm searching for a way of programmatically downloading files from Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `github.com` by `raw.githubusercontent.com` and remove `/blob` from the URL (which you can do it dynamically of course), then you automatically get the URL of the "raw" view of the same file.

Hence, a simple HTTP GET call on that URL will contain the content of the file in the body:

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String url = "https://github.com/Call-for-Code/Project-Sample/blob/main/sample-static-web/css/styles.css";
    System.out.println(getContent(url));
}

private String getContent(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    String rawUrl = url.replace("github.com", "raw.githubusercontent.com").replace("/blob", "");
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(rawUrl)).build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return response.body();
}
```

Of course, if the repository is private, you'll need to add an authentication to your HTTP request.

P.s. in my example I'm using Java 11's `java.net.*` Http client, but of course you can use whatever HTTP client you prefer (the concept is always the same).

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! What should be different if I want to make it on an enterprise github? How will it modify the url? Where do I place the credentials? Thanks alot!

Comment: The credentials can be added on the HTTP request easily (search "how to authenticate an HTTP request"). About the URL, I have no idea (I have noticed that by simply comparing the URL you initially provided against the URL I get clicking on "Raw" button)